# Cant use image from PIL library

Tags: python, python-3.x, image

I'm a new entry in this field. Recently, I started a course and one of the objects is to use image from PIL library. I installed it in my PowerShell terminal using : `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow` . But when I try to use the library in my Pycharm ide, it does not work. This is the whole code :

```py
from PIL.Image import Image

img = Image.open('.\pozepoc\pikachu.jpg')

print(img)
```

and i get an error saying

```
img = Image.open('.\pic\Picture.jpg')

AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'
```

also if i use the whole path of the folder of images like

```
img = Image.open('C:\Users\40729\Desktop\pic\Picture.jpg')
```

i get this error

```
img = Image.open('C:\Users\40729\Desktop\pic\Picture.jpg')

SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

I googled the problem, but I can't find the answer. Can someone explain what I have to do and why it does not work, I m looking for an explanation also because it's my learning journey that I m interested in most. Thank you.

Comment: This has nothing to do with images.  The problem is the unescaped backslashes.  When you write `\U` in a Python string, that introduces a Unicode escape character.  The solution is to convert all of the backslashes to forward slashes.  Windows accepts either one.  Alternatively, you could use `r` strings, as in `(r'C:\Users...')`.  The `r` tells Python to ignore escapes.

Comment: Also, use `from PIL import Image`.  You are getting `PIL.Image.Image`, which is not the function you want.